# Elastica get all results order by matched

Tags: php, symfony, elasticsearch, elastica

I am newer with elastica and i would like to get all products but sorting by favorites,

in my mode : poductDocument, i added a collection field to store the ids of users how added this product to favorite :

```
    class poductDocument implements DocumentInterface
    {

    private int $id;
    private string $label;
    private Collection $userIdsWhoAddedThisProductToFavorite;

    public function getId(): int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setId(int $id): self
    {
        $this->id = $id;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getLabel(): string
    {
        return $this->label;
    }

    public function setLabel(string $label): self
    {
        $this->label = $label;

        return $this;
    }
    public function getUserIdsWhoAddedThisProductToFavorite(): Collection
    {
        return $this->userIdsWhoAddedThisProductToFavorite;
    }

    public function setUserIdsWhoAddedThisProductToFavorite(array $data): self
    {
        $this->userIdsWhoAddedThisProductToFavorite = new ArrayCollection($data);

        return $this;
    }
}
```

And my mapping :

```
settings:
  number_of_replicas: 0
  number_of_shards: 1
  refresh_interval: 60s
mappings:
  dynamic: false
  properties:
    id:
      type: integer
    label:
      type: keyword
      fields:
        autocomplete:
          type: text
          analyzer: app_autocomplete
          search_analyzer: standard
        text:
          type: text
          analyzer: french
          fielddata: true
    user_ids_who_added_this_product_to_favorite:
      type: integer
```

And in my custom filter i used Query term to find my favorite products

```
public function applySort(Query $query, Query\BoolQuery $boolQuery): void
{
   $termQuery = new Query\Term();
   $termQuery->setTerm('user_ids_who_added_this_product_to_favorite', $this->getUser()->getId());
   $boolQuery->addMust($termQuery);
}
```

This code is working but give me just the favorite products, what i would like to do is to get all my product sorted by favorite product
for example if i have 4 products and i have product 1 and 2 as favorite my code give me :

```
product 1
product 2
```

and i'd like that the result be :

```
product 1
product 2
product 3
product 4
```

Any help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        $termQuery = new Query\Term();
        $termQuery->setTerm('user_ids_who_added_this_product_to_favorite', $this->getUser()->getId());
        $boolQuery->addShould($termQuery);
```